# oracle sql making procedure to show weekly ranking

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I made procedure to select weekly rank based on likes and views.
my sql query is like this below:

```
create or replace procedure select_rank
is
begin
  select count(billboard_user.user_idx) as likes, music.hit
  from billboard_user, user_like_music, music
  where billboard_user.user_idx = user_like_music.user_idx
    and user_like_music.music_idx = music.music_idx
  group by  music.hit
  order by count(billboard_user.user_idx) desc, music.hit desc;

end select_rank;
/
```

I was able to make procedure but oracle shows error

> **PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement**

So i tried this below:

```
create or replace procedure select_rank
  (v_rank number,
  v_title music.title%type,
  v_cnt number,
  v_release_date music.release_date%type,
  v_hit music.hit%type) is
begin
  select rank() over (order by count(billboard_user.user_idx) desc) as rank,
  music.title, music.release_date, count(billboard_user.user_idx) as likes, music.hit
  into v_rank, v_title, v_cnt, v_release_date, v_hit
  from billboard_user, user_like_music, music
  where billboard_user.user_idx = user_like_music.user_idx
    and user_like_music.music_idx = music.music_idx
  group by music.title, music.hit, music.release_date
  order by count(billboard_user.user_idx) desc, music.hit desc;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_rank: ' || v_rank);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_title: ' || v_title);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_cnt: ' || v_cnt);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_release_date: ' || v_release_date);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_hit: ' || v_hit);
end select_rank;
/
```

But it doesn't work as well. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `into` for each variable being selected:

```
declare
  v_title MUSIC.TITLE%type;
  v_cnt number;
  v_hit music.hit%type;
begin
  select music.title, count(melon_user.user_idx) as likes, music.hit
  into v_title, v_cnt, v_hit
  . . .
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Normally, this would go into out variables for the stored procedure.
- You can possibly do what you want just using a view, rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: I added those variables but I'm still getting error like this "expression 'V_RANK' cannot be used as an INTO-target  of a SELECT/FETCH statement. Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Interesting.  The code sample in this answer has nothing called `v_rank`.