# Oracle SQL Selecting weekly music rank procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm trying to make procedure to select weekly music rank based on hits and likes.

```
create or replace procedure select_rank(
  v_title         IN music.title%TYPE,
  v_release_date  IN music.release_date%TYPE, 
  v_hit           IN music.hit%TYPE
) is
    v_cnt number := 0;
  BEGIN
    select music.title, music.release_date, count(melon_user.user_idx) as likes, music.hit
    into v_rank, v_title, v_cnt, v_release_date, v_hit
    from melon_user, user_like_music, music
    where melon_user.user_idx = user_like_music.user_idx
      and user_like_music.music_idx = music.music_idx
    group by music.title, music.hit, music.release_date
    order by count(melon_user.user_idx) desc, music.hit desc;   
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_title: ' || v_title);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_cnt: ' || v_cnt);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_release_date: ' || v_release_date);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_hit: ' || v_hit);    
END select_rank;
/
```

But I keep getting error says

> PLS-00403: expression 'V_RELEASE_DATE' cannot be used as an
> INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement
>
> PLS-00403: expression 'V_RELEASE_DATE' cannot be used as an
> INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement
>
> PLS-00403: expression 'V_RELEASE_DATE' cannot be used as an
> INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement

how do I fix this?

Comment: This is more or less the same question as in your previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404484/oracle-sql-making-procedure-to-show-weekly-ranking

Comment: @GoranStefanović Yes I know, I'm really sorry but I've been really struggled for this. Because  I'm have mutiple table data from select statement so I tried to use bulk collect into but it doesn't work as well. And I have no idea about how to fix it.

Comment: There is no mention of bulk collect in any of your threads. Update questions with the latest changes you tried to make, and someone will be able to help you. One question: why are you insisting on PL/SQL procedure? Why don't you just create a view and use it for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In the procedure's signature you have:

```
v_release_date  IN music.release_date%TYPE,
```

`v_release_date` is an `IN` parameter and will be read only. If you want to assign values to it wthin the procedure and return them then make it an `OUT` (or `IN OUT`) parameter.

However, you have also:

- Not declared the `v_rank` variable.
- Your query appears likely to return multiple rows - `SELECT .. INTO ..` will only work for queries that return a single row. If this is the case then you either want to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` or return a cursor.